# In-kernel packet forwarding from one port to multiple ports

Tags: linux, port, iptables, forwarding, splice

On a Linux-based system I need data incoming on a TCP port to be automatically redirected to other 50 local ports without going through user-space's send/recv. Each port needs to receive a copy of all incoming traffic. All ports are local to the same machine.

I've discarded the `splice` syscall due to the limit of one endpoint being a file. I guess that `iptables` is the right tool for this purpose, but I can't figure out the right syntax for this purpose. It should be something similar to:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport <in_port> -j REDIRECT --to-ports <out_port1>-<out_port50>
```

I wonder e.g. if the option `-m multiport` is needed.

Comment: My first guess would have been to use the iptables `TEE` target, but [it doesn't work for stateful protocols like TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633114/how-to-handle-mirroredduplicated-iptables-traffic-after-tee).

Comment: I thought I'd to use `--match multiport`...

Comment: Hmm... actually using `TEE` with mangling the destination port could work, but using a regular TCP socket (instead of a raw socket) for the endpoint would probably not work. I think you can't work around writing an userspace application for this. You could use the `tee` (`man 2 tee`) system call though. Have you seen [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190731/send-data-to-multiple-sockets-using-pipes-tee-and-splice) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884934/does-linuxs-splice2-work-when-splicing-from-a-tcp-socket)?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately `splice` works on a TCP socket, but the other endpoint can't be a socket (e.g. it must be a file/pipe).